# Is there a way to extract to use emacs-clang-complete-async with a compilation database?

Tags: c++, emacs, clang++

[emacs-clang-complete-async](https://github.com/Golevka/emacs-clang-complete-async) uses clang to provide C++ autocompletion in Emacs.

Of course, it needs the appropriate project CFLAGS (-I...) to work properly.
Some tools such as CMake, Ninja, etc. are providing a json file, [the compilation database](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html), containing the list of the command used to compile each file during the compilation process.

I would like to use the content of this file and give it to emacs-clang-complete-async somehow. Does anyone has already succeeded to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any solution to this problem finally, keeping the question here in case the situation changes.